# How do I modify elements in an array that is managed by an Ember Controller?

Tags: ember.js

I'm probably missing something really silly, (Ember newbie) but I can't figure out how to modify an array that's under the management of my Ember Controller, other than to set an entirely new array.

For example. I have the following test function in my controller. When the user clicks, I want to modify each element of the controlled array (or it could be an individual element) with a new value.

I understand that you're supposed to go through "set" to make the changes known to Ember, so I thought this would work:

```
clickHandler:function(e){
    var temp = this.get("itemList").copy(); // copy it
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) { 
        temp[i].desc = "CANCELLED";     // change it
    }
    this.set('itemList', temp); // put it back
}
```

I make a copy of the array, modify it, and then set it back. But somehow Ember complains about the 4th line, where I modify the contents of temp[i].desc, saying I have to use Ember.Set. I assumed I could modify the "offline" copy and then set it back, but no-go and I can't figure out why. Other array operations, like shift/unshift/pop seem to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your approach does not look very emberish. This code would work:

```
clickHandler:function(e){
    var itemList = this.get("itemList");
    itemList.forEach(function(item){ // for iterating over an array, always use the forEach function
        item.set("desc", "CANCELLED"); // you have to call this set()-function to make changes to an Ember Object
    });
}
```

**Why do you need to call the set()-method and can't use your direct access approach?**

The set()-method enables Ember to perform its autobinding magic. When this method is called, it schedules all the stuff that needs to be performed on the objects that depend on the modified property. The easiest example is a template displaying that given property that would need an update.

**Here a possible improvement on the code above to make even more emberish:**
You could use an ArrayController to manage your itemList. In this case you would set your itemList as the content property of the controller. You will notice that lots of tutorials leverage this controller if dealing with an array.

```
App.ItemListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content : null, //set your itemList into this property
    clickHandler:function(e){
        this.get("content").setEach("desc", "CANCELLED");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You guys that take the time to educate us on Stack Overflow are awesome. Unfortunately, neither of these solutions is working for me. In both cases I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'" According to the debugger, the 'item' I'm getting back looks like it should work: 
item: Object
__ember1361578135008_meta: Meta
get desc: function () {
get name: function () {
set desc: function () {
set name: function () {
__proto__: Object

Comment: Your suggestion completely makes sense, I just can't figure out why it doesn't work. If I use an ArrayController and the line:
this.get("content").setEach('desc', "CANCELLED"); then I see all my template items get reset to "CANCELLED", so I know everything else is working, but if I use "forEach", the "item" I get passed back won't accept a "set" call. :^(

Comment: I was very happy too about 3 months ago when people helped me getting started. Can you put your example into a fiddle? I will post a link to a basic ember template in a couple of minutes.

Comment: It is based on my proposed solution. Have a look at it and tell me what does not work for you or modify it to show me what you would like to do with it :-)

Comment: Thanks again. I noticed in your example that rather than simply 'set'ing an array to 'content' you were using addObject. I was wondering if by using addObject/createObject that was what was giving access to the 'item.set()' function that was failing for me? Unfortunately, when I tried to change to using addObject(), it told me that was undefined as well. By any chance, did this stuff change recently? The code I inherited is using 1.0.0-pre.2. I don't actually need to change elements within the 'content' array for this task, but it would be nice to figure out why I can't.

Comment: The reason it works now is not the use of addObject. You can also set the array at once. See an alternative version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/XFFkW/2/

Comment: The reason it works is the use of **createObject** of Ember.Object. The object you pass to the method is wrapped in an instance of Ember.Object. And this instance has the method **set(key, value)**.

Comment: And i don't think that this stuff changed recently.

Comment: I never figured out why my app wouldn't work, and it was a bit too complex to but into jsfiddle, but I essential rewrote it from the ground up, moving to the latest version 1.0.0.rc.1, and using your example as my starting point and now my app is working okay and is more in sync with the docs. I'm still having difficulty understanding how to set it up so that more than one MVCs are on-screen at once. Worked okay with my original code, but I don't have it correct using the newer router, but that's a different topic. Thanks!